# How to pass data between two PreferenceFragmentCompat classes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences

I want to pass data like ***id*** to another **PreferenceFragmentCompat** class so that I could configure that specific group with the group id. In order to navigate between 2 Preference fragments you specify **app:fragment** in the preferences xml file or via code and set the arguments:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("id", "group id")

val preference = Preference(context).apply {
    title = "group name"
    key = "key"
    fragment ="io.foodless.fragments.preferences.GroupPreference"
    arguments = bundle
}
```

But in the **GroupPreference** class When I try to access the argument ***id*** returns null

```
class GroupPreference:PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.group_preference,rootKey)

        val groupId = arguments?.getString("id")
        Log.d("debug","data $groupId")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Preference.getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#getExtras()) it says

> Return the extras Bundle object associated with this preference, creating a new Bundle if there currently isn't one. You can use this to get and set individual extra key/value pairs.

So instead of making a new Bundle I called preference.getExtras() and it worked:

```
val preference = Preference(context).apply {
    title = "group name"
    key = "key"
    fragment ="io.foodless.fragments.preferences.GroupPreference"

    val bundle = extras
    bundle.putString("id", "group id")
}
```

Comment: you should also tell why the `onCreate` method can get the bundle